# Azure Data Factory converts date strings to unix timestamp

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-cosmosdb

I have an ADF that I want to use to copy documents between to CosmosDB containers. In the process, I wish to a a new column 'type' with a hardcoded value. It works great.

There is however 2 fields on the source documents (to/from) that are ISO8601 dates with UTC offset Z defined as strings. I.e `2022-11-04T22:59:59Z` is converted to `1667602799`.

I have not defined any such datetime transformations. My source dataset simply uses `select * from c` as a query. The documents do not have a common schema, although most to have the to/from fields.

When I view the preview data, and even download the excel preview, the dates are rendered as ISO8601 formatted. Only in the receiving cosmos container, are they formatted as unix timestamps.

This is my spec:

```
{
    "name": "transform qa",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "src_qa",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "dst_qa",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "sink1"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn1"
                }
            ],
            "scriptLines": [
                "source(allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     query: 'select * from c',",
                "     format: 'documentQuery',",
                "     systemColumns: false) ~> source1",
                "source1 derive(type = \"myType\") ~> derivedColumn1",
                "derivedColumn1 sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     deletable:false,",
                "     insertable:true,",
                "     updateable:true,",
                "     upsertable:true,",
                "     format: 'document',",
                "     partitionKey: ['/id'],",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> sink1"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make sure my fields are copied as defined in the src and not converted?

Answer (score 0):

> There is however 2 fields on the source documents (to/from) that are ISO8601 dates with UTC offset Z defined as strings. I.e `2022-11-04T22:59:59Z` is converted to `1667602799`.

To store the dates as same in source container, after providing query `select * from c` in source options you need to click on `Import projection` in that you need to change the data type in source projection from `datetime` to `string` as you can see in the below.

[image]

Below is the sample data stored in my source container:

```js
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "from": "2022-01-01T12:00:00Z",
    "to": "2022-01-02T12:00:00Z",
    "description": "Sample document 1"
}

{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Jane Smith",
    "from": "2022-02-01T08:00:00Z",
    "to": "2022-02-02T08:00:00Z",
    "description": "Sample document 2"
}

{
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Alice Johnson",
    "from": "2022-03-01T18:00:00Z",
    "to": "2022-03-02T18:00:00Z",
    "description": "Sample document 3"
}
```

After changing the data type to `string` below is the data stored in the other container by adding a new column `type`.

```js
{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "description": "Sample document 1",
    "to": "2022-01-02T12:00:00Z",
    "id": "1",
    "from": "2022-01-01T12:00:00Z",
    "type": "myType3"
}

{
    "name": "Jane Smith",
    "description": "Sample document 2",
    "to": "2022-02-02T08:00:00Z",
    "id": "2",
    "from": "2022-02-01T08:00:00Z",
    "type": "myType3"
}

{
    "name": "Alice Johnson",
    "description": "Sample document 3",
    "to": "2022-03-02T18:00:00Z",
    "id": "3",
    "from": "2022-03-01T18:00:00Z",
    "type": "myType3"
}
```